# Create add-in for Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, ms-office

What is the best/easiest way to create an add-in for Outlook 2010?

Will use VS2010 with C# for developing.

I need to:
-Store credentials.
-Access a web-service with credentials.
-Support shortcuts(not a must have).

Anyone tested [Add-in Express™ 2010](http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php) ?

-Stian

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried Add-in Express. I recommend using Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO). It comes built in with Visual Studio 2010. 
 You should have it under "Office->Outlook 2010 Add-in" in the new project dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I used Add-in Express for years and liked it so much I wanted to work for the company - now I do!  :-)  If you're new to add-in development, VSTO can be - well, less than enjoyable.  ADX is far quicker - and supports handling keyboard shortcuts in Outlook as well.  Not to mention you can write one add-in that works in all versions of Office from 2000-2010.